# Check if a value exists in Firebase using Python

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a [data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYdAN.png) as follows. I want to find out if there is a value named "John". I tried using:

```
db.reference(f"User/{user.id}").child("Character").order_by_child("name").equal_to("John").get()
```

This raised the error `Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "name"`. I tried Frank's suggestion and [added to the rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WryN0.png) but it does not seem to work.
I'm out of ideas on how to do this, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "order_by_child can only sort numbers" That's not true. If the documentation led you to believe that, can you please edit your question to include the exact part that led you there? --- Aside from that: did you already [search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Index+not+defined%2C+add+%22.indexOn%22%3A+%22name%22) you got? It's pretty common, and I'm quite sure it's been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need to [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-child) in the security rules of your database to allow this query. Something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "user": {
      "character": {
        ".indexOn": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```